# text going out of container in destop & Mobile

Tags: html, css

```
    .Scontainer {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #040519;
            background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/S3jrs2v/1.jpg');
            background-position: -20% 0px;
            background-size: 60%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 480px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        
        .container-widths {
            font-family: 'Raleway';
            width: 90%;
            position: relative;
            top: 8%;
            left: 45%;
            width: 50%;
        }
        
        .am-content {
            position: relative;
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 95%;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 60px;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            
        }
    
        

    <section id="wrapper"   >
        <div class="Scontainer"></div>
        <div class="container-widths" id="qwer">
            <div class="am-content">
                <div class="stitle">GOLDSMTH </div>
                <div class="subtitle"><span style="color: red">TEACHING FOR 19 YEARS</span>
                    <br> Lisa Witt has been teaching piano for 19 years and in that time has helped hundreds of students learn to play the songs they love. Lisa received classical piano training through the Royal Conservatory of Music, but she has since embraced popular music and playing by ear in order to accompany herself and others. She is a songwriter and recording artist. Lisa’s contagious enthusiasm will have you excited to practice and return to the keys for your next lesson. Her teaching style focuses on you, making lessons encouraging and fun.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

In this HTML when I increase the height, the text crossing the background. I can't solve the problem. I need, when I increase the text height background also wants to go down at the same time. can you please solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to position the `.container-widths` as `absolute`.

```
.container-widths {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

```css
.Scontainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #040519;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/S3jrs2v/1.jpg');
  background-position: -20% 0px;
  background-size: 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 480px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container-widths {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 50%;
}

.am-content {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section id="wrapper">
  <div class="Scontainer"></div>
  <div class="container-widths" id="qwer">
    <div class="am-content">
      <div class="stitle">GOLDSMTH </div>
      <div class="subtitle"><span style="color: red">TEACHING FOR 19 YEARS</span>
        <br> Lisa Witt has been teaching piano for 19 years and in that time has helped hundreds of students learn to play the songs they love. Lisa received classical piano training through the Royal Conservatory of Music, but she has since embraced
        popular music and playing by ear in order to accompany herself and others. She is a songwriter and recording artist. Lisa’s contagious enthusiasm will have you excited to practice and return to the keys for your next lesson. Her teaching style
        focuses on you, making lessons encouraging and fun.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```